# Executing a python script from PHP to open a socket

Tags: apache-2.2, php, python

I have a python script chatserver.py that includes:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
<SNIP>
reactor.listenTCP(3800, factory)
print "Server Started"
reactor.run()
```

This opens a socket on port 3800 which works if I start from SSH but I want to do a check for the open port and if it is closed reopen using PHP but I cannot seem to get the python script to execute.

Here is how I am calling it via PHP at the moment

```
function serverCheck() {
$host = "MYHOST";
$port = 3800;
$connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

if ( !is_resource($connection) ) { // port not open
exec('/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/chat/chatserver.py',$output);
var_dump($output);

if($connection)
fclose($connection);
}
}
```

I have tried a lot of things I have found on my searches but I just cannot seem to get the file to execute.

A nice guy was helping me out at SO but couldn't figure out the answer so redirected me to here.

My files are chmod correctly and the function "serverCheck" 100% gets hit but the python script never seems to get executed!

Comment: To expand: `httpd` is running by user `apache`. User `apache` is in group `chatserver`. The py and php files are both `755` and owned by group `chatserver`. The rest of the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836116/executing-a-python-script-from-php-to-open-a-socket

Comment: What happens when you try to execute the script? Where is your error checking?!

Comment: I get `array(0) {}` printed out from `var_dump($output);` and the file doesnt get executed!

Comment: What does your apache error log say ?